# Primefaces Responsive design

Tags: java, primefaces, responsive-design, facelets

I wonder if there is a framework, or a library that allows me to develop a web application using Primefaces and the template or layout is responsive according to the screen display.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***(Sorry for the late reply here, it popped up on a search).*** I've had pretty good luck using Twitter Bootstrap with Primefaces. Generally speaking you're going to need to pay attention to data-tables and all the other components that don't work well with mobile, but overall I've been pretty happy.

Additionally Primefaces has a skin to support the look and feel of bootstrap so you can do a lot right out of the box.

Downside? It is going to look like a bootstrap application. Upside? You don't need to do all the responsive work up front and for most sites that's enough.

Comment: Did you use primefaces mobile or just plain primefaces?

Comment: @user3586195 I use just plain Primefaces. Primefaces Mobile is pretty mobile jquery mobile and I prefer the responsive bootstrap layouts over having two sites.

Comment: Which version of primefaces with which version of bootstrap ?

Comment: I used this a long time ago, I last developed a stable application using Primefaces 3.3 and Bootstrap 2, however Primefaces now has a bootstrap theme and I suspect you can integrate them easily. There really isn't much of a conflict. You're just integrating jQueryUI (Primefaces) and Bootstrap. Composite components will really help you. I suspect you could be up and running in an hour or so.